# How to click multiple buttons with same class using Appium with Python

Tags: python, appium

I am trying to create a bot that will automatically unfollow all the currently followed users on Depop.

I can get it as far as unfollowing the first user in the followed user list.

The problem is, all the unfollow buttons use the same class with the text 'Following'

I have created a while loop which I hoped would click on all the currently displayed buttons that contain the text 'Following'. However; it will only 'click' the first button.

```
    unfollow = 'yes'
    while unfollow == 'yes':
        if driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.Button'):
        followBtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.Button')
        btnText = followBtn.text

        if btnText == 'Following':
            followBtn.click()
        else:
            unfollow = 'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `driver.find_elements()` and store all elements in a dictionary and iterate them.
finally, check again if any button exists, also you cannot use driver.find() as a condition and you should use try/except block to reach this.

So this is the answer:

```
unfollow = 'yes'
while unfollow == 'yes':
  try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.Button')
  except:
    return
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('android.widget.Button')
  for el in elements:
  btnText = el.text
  if btnText == 'Following':
      el.click()
  else:
    unfollow = 'no'
    return
```